# Print Oracle PLSQL OUT variable

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

```
create or replace package demo_pckg 
as
 type cursor_type is ref cursor;
 procedure demo_proc(i_deptno number,o_result out cursor_type);
end;
/


create or  replace package body demo_pckg
as
procedure demo_proc(i_deptno number,o_result out cursor_type)
as
 begin
    open o_result for
    select * from employees 
    where department_id=i_deptno;
    end;
end;
/
```

What should I do in case I want to print that OUT cursor variable ?

Comment: What do you mean by "print"? Display the resultset in sqlplus? Something else?

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way from SQL*Plus or SQL Developer is with [`variable`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve050.htm) and [`print`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve031.htm):

```
var deptno number
var result refcursor
exec :deptno := 10;
exec demo_pckg.demo_proc(:deptno, :result);
print result
```

Or:

```
var result refcursor
declare
  deptno emplyees.department_id%type;;
begin
  deptno := 10;
  demo_pckg.demo_proc(deptno, :result);
end;
/
print result
```

The `result` is treated as a bind variable in the procedure call, so it's prefixed with `:` there, but it's a native variable to SQL*Plus so it doesn't have one for the `print` call. You can run either in SQL*Plus, or as a script in SQL Developer, which will show the results in the Script Output window.

You can hard-code the `deptno` value in the procedure call in either case, of course, rather than delcaring a variable to hold that.

If you're calling this from Java or some other client program you can treat your `OUT` cursor like any other result set.

You can also declare `result` as a `sys_refcursor` in your procedure, rather than declaring your own type.

Answer (score 1):

`dbms_output.put_line` prints to standard output. You need to enable server output to see the results with: `set serveroutput on`. Turning server output on should be done in your environment like sqlplus, etc.
You will need to select results into a variable with `select column1 into var1 from ...` so that you can print them later with `dbms_output.put_line('my var1: ' || var1);`