# Call Oracle Stored Procedure with PL/SQL in TOAD

Tags: oracle, plsql, output

I am trying to call a stored procedure in TOAD from PL/SQL that has both OUT parameters and a SYS_REFCURSOR.  When I try to execute the block below, I get `ORA-01008: not all variables bound` but I cannot determine which is the issue.  I am prompted with a form to bind rtnData, so it doesnt seem to be that one.

```
declare
    QueryTime DATE;
    ErrorNum NUMBER;
    ErrorDesc VARCHAR2(2000);
    type rtnData is ref cursor;
begin  
  MyProcedure(to_date('01/01/2010', 'MM/DD/YYYY'), QueryTime, ErrorNum, ErrorDesc, :rtnData);
  dbms_output.put_line(rdbQueryTime);
  dbms_output.put_line(rtnErrorNum);
  dbms_output.put_line(rtnErrorDesc);
end;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`rtnData` is declared in the PL/SQL block, so you don't have to treat it as a bind variable - so it should not have a colon in front of it.

But `rtnData` is declared as a type, not as a variable. You don't need your own type, so it should be:

```
declare
  QueryTime DATE;
  ErrorNum NUMBER;
  ErrorDesc VARCHAR2(2000);
  rtnData sys_refcursor;
begin
  MyProcedure(to_date('01/01/2010', 'MM/DD/YYYY'), QueryTime, ErrorNum,
    ErrorDesc, rtnData);
...
```

If you're prompted for a form to set rtnData you'll still get that error if you don't set it, or if the parameter is declared as `OUT` in the `MyProcedure` declaration.

To display the ref cursor in a data grid in Toad, I *think* you need this:

```
declare
  QueryTime DATE;
  ErrorNum NUMBER;
  ErrorDesc VARCHAR2(2000);
begin
  MyProcedure(to_date('01/01/2010', 'MM/DD/YYYY'), QueryTime, ErrorNum,
    ErrorDesc, :rtnData);
...
```

... and then execute as a script, and choose 'cursor' as the bind type when prompted. I'm not able to test that though. ([This suggests it'll work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/953831/266304), but not sure why it's declaring the type as it isn't used).

Comment: ErrorNum, ErrorDesc and rtnData are all declared as OUT parameters in the stored procedure.  What do I have to do to get the procedure to execute in TOAD with OUT parameters?

Comment: @MichaelKingsmill - it will execute as it is here. You've declared variables for your block, so they can be passed to the procedure as `OUT` parameters. Are you still getting an error? What do you plan to do with the cursor, `rtnData`, when you get it back from the procedure?

Comment: I was still getting an error, but I realize now that was related to using the "Execute Statement" button rather than "Execute as Script" button.  I get the output parameters printed to the output window which I would expect, but I want to get the cursor output to the datagrid window.

Comment: @MichaelKingsmill - right, not sure how to do that in Toad, I don't use it. In SQL*Plus or SQL Developer I'd [use `variable` and `print`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21218949/266304); possibly Toad supports those but I really don't know I'm afraid.

Comment: @MichaelKingsmill - yeah, thought it might, but wondered if execute-as-script might be a factor still. It's definitely declared as `OUT`, not `IN OUT`? Seems like that should work, but afraid I've only read about it. Sorry.

Comment: Nevermind, that was working, I just wasn't looking at the correct output window.  Thanks for sticking with me on this!